# Sorting array elements and indices, and outputting in table form

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

The Java program below asks the user for UP TO 25 test scores, it then stores them in an array, averages them, and prints out in table form the inputted test grades as well as the calculated average. There is an unused sorting algorithm present as its own method named selectionSort. This is actually from a textbook.

I need to use that method to sort the array and create an additional output like the second example shown below where the test scores are displayed in ascending order. The only hint I have is that I need to make another array of the indices of the first array.

I'm not supposed to put any additional code in the main method, so I assume I will need a separate method? Or can I put all of the additional code in the selectionSort method so I only have to call one method? All I understand is that the selectionSort method sorts the elements, but not the indices so it won't show Test 1, 2, 3 like it's supposed to. So I need to sort the indices as well, and then somehow print both? How do I do this? Thanks

The current output is like this.

[unsorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbLhg.png)

I need an additional output like this. "Table of sorted test scores"

[sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZgl.png)

```
public class ArrayIntro2 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //integer array
       int [] TestGrades = new int[25];
       
       //creating object of ArrayIntro2T
       ArrayIntro2T pass = new ArrayIntro2T(TestGrades, 0, 0, 0);
       
       //getting total and filling array
       int scoreCount = ArrayIntro2T.FillArray(TestGrades, 0);
       
       //get average score
       double avg = pass.ComputeAverage(TestGrades, scoreCount);
       
       
       
       //outputting table
       ArrayIntro2T.OutputArray(TestGrades,scoreCount,avg);
        
    }
    
}

    //new class to store methods
     class ArrayIntro2T{
    //variable declaration    
    
    double CalcAvg = 0;
    int ScoreTotal = 0;
    int ScoreCount = 0;
    int [] TestGrades = new int[25];
    
       
    
        //constructor
        public ArrayIntro2T(int [] TestGradesT, int ScoreCountT, double CalcAvgT, int ScoreTotalT)
        {
            TestGrades = TestGradesT;
            ScoreCount = ScoreCountT;
            CalcAvg = CalcAvgT;
            ScoreTotal = ScoreTotalT;
            
            
        }
        //method to fill array
        public static int FillArray(int [] TestGrades, int ScoreCount)
    {
        
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
         System.out.println("Please enter test scores one at a time, up to 25 values or enter -1 to quit" );
         TestGrades[ScoreCount]= scan.nextInt();
    
         if(TestGrades[ScoreCount]==-1)
           {
              System.out.println("You have chosen to quit ");
           }
    
        while(TestGrades[ScoreCount]>=0 && ScoreCount<=25)
           {
                ScoreCount++;
                System.out.println("Enter the next test score or -1 to finish ");
                TestGrades[ScoreCount] = scan.nextInt();
           }
        return ScoreCount;
       
    
    }
        //method to compute average
        public double ComputeAverage(int [] TestGrades,int ScoreCount)
    {
        
        for(int i=0; i<ScoreCount;i++)
           {
                ScoreTotal += TestGrades[i];
                CalcAvg = (double)ScoreTotal/(double)ScoreCount;   
           }
        
        return CalcAvg;
        
    }
        
        public static void selectionSort(int[] TestGrades){
            int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;
            for(startScan=0; startScan<(TestGrades.length-1);startScan++){
                minIndex = startScan;
                minValue = TestGrades[startScan];
                  for(index = startScan+1;index<TestGrades.length; index++){
                      if(TestGrades[index]<minValue)
                      {
                          minValue=TestGrades[index];
                          minIndex=index;
                      }
                  }
                  TestGrades[minIndex]=TestGrades[startScan];
                  TestGrades[startScan]=minValue;
            }
        }
        //method to output scores and average
        public static void OutputArray(int [] TestGrades,int ScoreCount, double CalcAvg)
    {
        
        System.out.println("Grade Number\t\tGrade Value");
       
        for(int i=0; i<ScoreCount;i++)
           {
            System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+"\t"+"\t"+TestGrades[i]);
           }
    
    System.out.printf("Calculated Average\t"+ "%.2f%%", CalcAvg);
    
  
        
    }
       
    }
```

I've tried calling the selectionSort method in the main method, and also using Array.sort although they produce the same result. When I do that, I get an output that looks like this:

[failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPaoX.png)

Comment: I was told by my teacher as a hint that I need to make a separate array for the indices. Also, the array only contains the scores entered by the user, there are no other elements. The array is defined by the user, if they enter less than 25 elements, the array will be the size of however many elements they entered. They just cannot enter more than 25. Yes, I can call the selectionSort in the main method, but it will result in the nonsensical output I showed.

Comment: I think I understand now. the ScoreCount variable keeps track of how many scores the user enters. The array is still always sized for 25 elements so it's a partial array. In that case it sounds like I should make a new array of only the elements entered by the user and sort that array like so:    int [] testGrade2 = new int [ScoreCount];  

for(int i=0; i<ScoreCount;i++)
           {
                testGrade2[i] = TestGrades[i]; 
           }

Answer (score 0):

Why are you thinking about sorting the indices? The sorted output that you expect doesn't change the order of the indices. Adding the call to `selectionSort()` in the `main` method makes sense, but if you're not supposed to do that, you can add it at the end of `FillArray()`, or the start of `OutputArray()`.

As to the issue with your output, you need to look into sorting *only* the scores that were entered by the user, and not every entry in the array.